# Cloudformation Condition to see if an SSM Parameter is set or not

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I have this particular value I am reading from the SSM parameter "SecretFeature" that I'm using as a Lambda's env variable:
`SecretFeature: "{{resolve:ssm: SecretFeature}}"`

However, that SSM parameter may or may not be set in some deployments. I want it to use that SSM parameter if it is defined, or else use a default value "None" as the fallback.

Something like:

```yaml
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyLambda
      Runtime: python3.8
      Handler: index.handler
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SecretFeature: 
            Fn::If:
              - SSMParameterExists
              - "{{resolve:ssm: SecretFeature}}"
              - "None"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a parameter with SSM type and then creating a condition [1] to check if it is empty or not.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

Comment: What if I don't want that SSM Parameter to be set in some deployments? I only want it set in a few select deployments?

Comment: If you are able to leave this decision up to the end-user deploying the stack, you could create an additional parameter called "Set SSM Parameter" with a Yes/No option and an additional condition to check for this response. This would let whoever is deploying manually specify that the SSM parameter should not be set, even if your secret is not empty.